# What is the cause of frequent corrupted/incomplete download from Amazon CDN to iOS devices?

Tags: ios, download, asihttprequest, corrupt-data

I mentioned Amazon CDN and iOS devices because I am not sure which part is the culprit.

I host jpg and PDF files in Amazon CDN.
I have an iOS application that download a large number of jpg and PDF files in a queue. I have tried using dataWithContentOfURL and ASIHttpRequest, but I get the same result. ASIHttpRequest at least gives a callback to indicate that there is problem with the download, so I can force it to retry.

But this happens very often. Out of 100 files, usually 1-5 files have to be redownloaded. If I check the file size, it is smaller than the original file size and can't be opened. 
The corrupted files are usually different everytime.

I've tried this on different ISP and network. It's the same.

Is there a configuration that I missed out in Amazon CDN, or is there something else I missed out in iOS doWnload? Is it not recommended to queue large number of files for download?

Comment: "ASIHttpRequest at least gives a callback to indicate that there is problem with the download, so I can force it to retry." - what error does it report?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't download more than 3 or 4 items at once on an iPhone. Regardless of implementation limitations (`ASIHTTPRequest` is decent anyway) or the potential for disk thrashing, you have to code for the 3G use case unless your app is explicitly marked (as in, with an `Info.plist` setting) that it requires Wi-Fi.

A solution exists within `ASIHTTPRequest` itself to make these operations sequential rather than concurrent. Add your `ASIHTTPRequest` objects to an `ASINetworkQueue` (the one returned by `[ASINetworkQueue queue]` will do fine). They will be executed one after the other.

Note that if you encounter any errors, all the requests on the queue will by default be cancelled unless you set the queue's `shouldCancelAllRequestsOnFailure` to `NO`.

*EDIT:* I just noticed you already mentioned using a download queue. I would therefore suspect it's more of an issue at the other end than on your device. Connections could be dropping for various reasons: keep-alive setting is too short, resources too low on the server so it's timing out, some part of the physical link between the server and the Internet backbone is failing intermittently. To be sure, though, you probably need to test your app on multiple devices to make sure it's consistently failing across all of them to really be able to say that.

Comment: Hi, yes I do queue them in a single thread, so they are sequential. Only one file at a time.

Comment: I have tested it on multiple devices. Same result

Comment: Definitely investigate the other end then. Sorry I can't really help you further since I'm a client-side (iOS) dev.

Comment: Thanks. Same here. I'm client-side as well. Just wondering if it's iOS side error, though I'm very convinced it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly try reducing the number of concurrent downloads:

```
ASIHTTPRequest.sharedQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 2;
```

This changes the default ASIHTTPRequest queue - if you're using your own queue set the value on that instead.

The default is 4, which is above the limit recommended by the HTTP 1.1 RFC when using persistent connections and when all the content is on the same server.